# How to completely fill an object with fluid?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I know how to make obstacles and inflows in Blender, but I do not know how to simply select an object and have it be filled totally with fluid.

What tool/command/setting do I need to have an obstacle become filled with fluid?

Comment: Short answer for now - model a mesh roughly in the shape of the fluid. Put it inside your container/obstacle. Designate it as a fluid in the sim settings.

Comment: That was what I tried first, but it tends to create problems with fluid clipping the container, flowing out, and acting strangely.

Comment: I know what you mean. Some things to consider include 1. mesh density (sometimes denser is better), 2. real world size of the fluid (sometimes larger is better), and 3. mesh topology (if there is non-manifold geometry or inverted normals you will have problems)... I hope that points you in the right direction. You'll probably need to experiment a bit.

Comment: if you limit the domain to the container size, it won't go out :)

Comment: Normals need to be reset for fluid to exist inside the obstacle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no shortcut at all. My idea could be select the inner side of your container mesh and duplicate it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. 
Then press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate the selection into another object.
You can try to make new mesh closed by selecting its top loop and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> and with luck get it close without much work (the mesh must be closed the Fluid sim to work).
Then add Fluid modifier in Physics panel.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it more clear; hope the edits represent your idea.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to simply put an inflow object inside your obstacle and let it fill up. That's how I would do it.